# Meaning distinction

Tags: word-choice

Tell me the difference between the two sentences.

> She is to swim twice a week.
>
> She has to swim twice a week.

Thanks in advance.

I want to know if it is possible to use "be to" as a habitual obligation "You are to call her" meaning it is my regular duty/obligation to call her or I have to call her every day.

Comment: To ***have to*** (usually pronounced HAFF, or HASS in your example) strongly implies ***obligation***. But if someone/something ***is to** [do something, or happen]*, that may just be a "prediction" or "scheduled activity", with no particularly strong allusions to "necessity" (but it's formal/dated phrasing).

Comment: Can it be a habitual obligation?

Comment: I mean the first sentence?

Comment: I don't know ***what*** you mean! As per my first comment, the *actual words* in your two examples would normally carry different implications, and the narture of those differences is fully covered by comments / answers both here and in the earlier duplicate I linked to above. There are several more ELL questions about the same thing - have a look at [Difference between “I have got to study on weekends” and “I have to study on weekends”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96113/).

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> She has to swim twice a week.

This means that she must swim twice a week, or has some kind of obligation to swim twice a week, or that someone or something is mandating her to swim twice a week (it could be her health, her sports coach, a commitment to a personal goal, etc. - this would be determined by the context).

> She is to swim twice a week.

This is quite a formal way of speaking, and could mean that there are plans for her to swim twice a week, i.e. it's part of a schedule or is anticipated/expected (again, the context would likely provide more information).

Comment: can the first sentence be a habitual obligation?  It is an obligation for her to swim twice a week.

Comment: It would almost certainly be a habitual obligation, being done twice per week, every week (within some set duration).

Comment: Your previous comment does not say it is an obligation. It says that it is an schedule as in "The prime minister is to visit London".

Comment: Did you explain it in two different angles. This is, you have included both schedule and obligation?

Comment: Sorry, I had reversed the quotes in my answer. "Is to" could be an obligation, for example, if someone is reiterating something that a sports coach or doctor, etc. had said - it is an obligation, but the person may say it as, "She is to swim twice a week." Again, this is quite formal and perhaps a bit dated, and more often you would hear "has to" or perhaps "needs to" in those scenarios.

Comment: Now I got the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem - please mark the answer as correct if it is so.